# ¿Cómo finalizar programa con espacio en blanco y Enter en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito finalizar el programa al ingresar un espacio en blanco y luego presionar Enter

esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora, pero no lo he logrado

```
Contador = 0
while True:
    try:
        Suma_Numeros = int(input('Ingrese el numero que desee sumar: '))
        Contador += Suma_Numeros
        print(Contador)
    except ValueError: 
        print('Error en caracter ingresado, por favor ingrese solo numeros')
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: antes de convertir a entero el input debes hacer `if not Suma_Numeros.strip(): break` y luego haces la conversión `Suma_Numeros = int(Suma_Numeros)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes comprobar antes del casteo a entero que el string introducido corresponde a un espacio en blanco " " y si es asi sales del bucle con un break :)

```
Contador = 0
while True:
    try:
        Suma_Numeros = input('Ingrese el numero que desee sumar: ')
        if Suma_Numeros == " ": break
        Suma_Numeros = int(Suma_Numeros)
        Contador += Suma_Numeros
        print(Contador)
    except ValueError: 
        print('Error en caracter ingresado, por favor ingrese solo numeros')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!